# iPad develop:customized button on navigationBar can't see after push->pop

Tags: ipad, button, customization

**iPad app**:I've add some customized button to navigationBar as follows:

```
- (void)addEditButton{
    UIButton *editButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    editButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 30);
    [editButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage        imageNamed:@"images_iPad.bundle/NavigationBar_Btn_iPad.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15/2.0 topCapHeight:32/2.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [editButton setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    editButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kAPPBOLDFONT size:12];
    editButton.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    editButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);

    UIBarButtonItem *editItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:editButton] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editItem;
```

}

My problem is that:I clicked this button,it will push to another viewController, after popModelViewController:animate,I can't see this customized button, although this, it does work.and not just here ,others are the same,please help me.